# How can I get the Contact Form "Manage Display" Settings programmatically?

Tags: 8, forms, emails

I am trying to use `hook_mail_alter` to create a custom contact mail.

I want to get the display setting of the contact form.

(example path: http://mysite/admin/structure/contact/manage/my_contact_form/display/mail)

The things I want to know are:

- Field Label
- If its disabled or not
- Field order
- Field ID

How can I get this information in the PHP script?

EDIT:

I was able to get most of the information I wanted. but I couldn't get the field weight to display in the right order. I have a display mode called 'mail' and I want to get the weight of each field in this mode.

for now the code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function contact_plus_mail_alter(&$message) {
    if (isset($message['id']) && $message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {

        $siteName = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
        $siteMail = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
        /** @var \Drupal\contact\Entity\Message $contactMessage */
        $contactMessage = $message['params']['contact_message'];
        $entityType = $contactMessage->getEntityType()->id();
        $bundle = $contactMessage->bundle();

        $contactForm = $contactMessage->getContactForm();
        $form_title = $contactForm->label();
        $recipients = implode(',', $contactForm->getRecipients());
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface[] $fields */
        $fields = $contactMessage->getFields();
        $data = [
            'title' => $form_title,
            'fields' => [],
        ];
        foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
            $fieldDefinition = $field->getFieldDefinition();
            $data['fields'][] = [
                'label' => $fieldDefinition->getLabel(),
                'info' => $field->getValue(),
                'display_options' => $fieldDefinition->getDisplayOptions(),
                'weight' => '', // I want to get the field weight for the 'mail' display mode.
            ];
        }
        // TODO: order the data by weight

        // ... send the email
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is composing your email body using the fields values, labels and display options from your form mode for a given entity, in this case 'contact_message' entity. Am I right? If that is the case I would use a view mode with the exact same layout as the form and use a theme suggestion (like `contact-message--mail.html.twig` assuming the view mode is `mail`) to customize the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. but I cant see how I would get the fields with it's settings in the twig. I solved my problem with the `getComponents()` function. Here is how: [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266205/how-can-i-get-the-contact-form-manage-display-settings-programmatically/266321#266321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the order of the 'mail' display.
The secret was in the `->getComponets()` function in this part:

```
$display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('entity_view_display')
    ->load($entityType . '.' . $bundle . '.' . $displayMode);
$displayFields = $display->getComponents();
```

the final code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function contact_plus_mail_alter(&$message) {
    if (isset($message['id']) && $message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {
        $message['send'] = false;

        $siteName = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
        $siteMail = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');

        /** @var \Drupal\contact\Entity\Message $contactMessage */
        $contactMessage = $message['params']['contact_message'];
        $entityType = $contactMessage->getEntityType()->id();
        $bundle = $contactMessage->bundle();
        $contactForm = $contactMessage->getContactForm();
        $form_title = $contactForm->label();
        $recipients = implode(',', $contactForm->getRecipients());
        // Data for the email
        $data = [
            'title' => $form_title,
            'today' => (new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')))->format('m/d/Y'),
            'fields' => [],
        ];
        // get the 'mail' display mode if defined
        $viewModes = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')
            ->getViewModeOptionsByBundle(
                $entityType, $bundle
            );
        $displayMode = array_key_exists('mail', $viewModes) ? 'mail' : 'default';

        // get display field settings (weight, id, etc...)
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay $display */
        $display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('entity_view_display')
            ->load($entityType . '.' . $bundle . '.' . $displayMode);
        $displayFields = $display->getComponents();

        // put the fields info in the email data
        foreach ($displayFields as $key => $fieldConfig) {
            $field = $contactMessage->get($key);
            $fieldDefinition = $field->getFieldDefinition();
            $data['fields'][$key] = [
                'label' => $fieldDefinition->getLabel(),
                'info' => $field->getValue(),
                'display_options' => $fieldDefinition->getDisplayOptions(),
                'weight' => $fieldConfig['weight'],
            ];
        }

        // order by weight
        function compare_weight($a, $b) {
            return strnatcmp($a['weight'], $b['weight']);
        }
        uasort($data['fields'], 'compare_weight');

        // send the email for the responsible
        $emailSender = new EmailSender($siteName . '<' . $siteMail . '>', $recipients, $form_title, 'my_theme', $data);
        $emailSender->createAndSendEmail();

        // send a copy to the person who filed the form
        if (isset($data['fields']['field_email'])) {
            $email = $data['fields']['field_email']['info'][0]['value'];
            $emailSender->to = $email;
        }
        $emailSender->createAndSendEmail();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.